# Proving existence of Itō Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Here's an extract from some Continuous Martingales notes

[image]

I can see how K-W implies the blue box inequality but how does that inequality give continuity? Also what is the functional theorem that requires this continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the statement that a [bounded linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) (or functional, in this case) on a normed space is continuous.

And second, the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem). The easy direction of that theorem is the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)